# Como esconder imagens da pasta 'Resources'?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources

Como crio um arquivo para pôr as imagens da pasta 'resources'? Não quero que as pessoas que usarem meu programa tenham acesso a elas. O arquivo pode ser qualquer extensão.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Queres esconder recursos do projecto?
Podes embuti-los/incorpora-los na assembly.

Basta ir as propriedades do ficheiro dentro do Visual Studio, e onde diz `Build Action`, selecionar `Embedded Resource`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois podes ler o ficheiro da seguinte maneira (caso seja um ficheiro de texto):

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".ficheiro.txt";

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```